# How is this website redirect working?

Tags: phishing, scam

Someone sent me a URL via WhatsApp (`httpx://cadburys-prizes[.]com`) that allegedly lets me claim a free box of chocolates. Obviously this is fake and I've seen similar websites before.

If I view the URL on my phone I end up at `httpx://cadburys-prizes[dot]com/#forward` where I'm prompted to answer some questions and then spam my WA contacts with further messages.

Viewing the source code for the page (by wget'ting it) , I can see a redirect to a bit.ly address. When I open the `cadburys-prizes[.]com` url on a (sanitized, virtual) desktop browser I get redirected to the bit.ly address which, judging from the URL, is a fake tech support site (the content is getting blocked by my network defences but I can imagine the scene).

What I don't understand is where the survey that shows on iPhone comes from? There is nothing I can see in the source of that page. Is it possible for an invisible proxy to be presenting a different index.html based on the user agent string? I did try to wget the page with mobile Safari UA but got the same result as without it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various ways to fingerprint a client you're using. User-agent string is only a famous one. If you view the source code for `cadburys-prizes[.]com`, it uses `meta` refresh to redirect to `httpx://bit[.]ly/2K1V332` after 2 seconds. It's possible that `cadubrys-prizes` may serve different content without using bit.ly. The bit.ly URL redirects to `httpx://cash[.]trxmonetizer[.]com` which seems to be doing the main job i.e. fingerprinting the client and presenting with whatever they feel like.

If it's doing everything on client, you can imitate any User-agent and inspect the response to dig deeper. However, it's also possible to do it on server-side for which they may or may not pass fingerprinting parameters in the request.